# remove INSTALL project from llvm built using cmake

Tags: build, cmake, llvm

I am using cmake to build llvm and the problem is that annoying little INSTALL project getting generated. I don't know how to remove that project.I don't want to install my built components. Can anybody help me not generating INSTALL project through cmake ? I tried to edit the CmakeLists.txt provided by llvm and commented out the install specific lines as follows :

```
#install(DIRECTORY include/
#  DESTINATION include
#  FILES_MATCHING
#  PATTERN "*.def"
#  PATTERN "*.h"
#  PATTERN "*.td"
#  PATTERN "*.inc"
#  PATTERN "LICENSE.TXT"
#  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
#  )

#install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/
#  DESTINATION include
#  FILES_MATCHING
#  PATTERN "*.def"
#  PATTERN "*.h"
#  PATTERN "*.gen"
#  PATTERN "*.inc"
  # Exclude include/llvm/CMakeFiles/intrinsics_gen.dir, matched by "*.def"
#  PATTERN "CMakeFiles" EXCLUDE
#  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
#  )
```

But that doesn't help either. Any inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several places in the llvm sources where CMake's `install` command is used.  You need to remove every instance to get rid of the `INSTALL` target entirely.

To find these places, try doing a recursive search of all .txt files and all .cmake files:

```
cd <path to root of llvm sources>
findstr /ins install( *.txt
findstr /ins install( *.cmake
```